Zabbix Agent is not available with frequency
I have some SERVERS with zabbix agent 6.4 installed and passive monitoring with zabbix proxy installed and configured correctly.
The problem is that, sometimes and with a lot of frequency, this loses data  and i get the not available state on the Operational data,during a brief period of time for becoming resolved minutes later as you can see on the screenshot.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have checked the server, and there's no reboot during these times.
So what might be the problem and how can I solve it?

What does your log show?

I have checked the file zabbix_agentd.log that is located on the SERVER and I have seen this line multiple times:
7708:20240722:034051.309 get_perf_counter_value_by_path(): call to PdhOpenQuery() failed: [0x00000102] unable to find message text: [0x0000013D] El sistema no puede encontrar el texto del mensaje para el mensaje número 0x%1 en el archivo de mensajes para %2.

What does it mean? What might be happening? Do I have to check anything else?

Are these agents monitored through the proxy? Is the proxy itself available and well-behaving all the time? // It is very hard to help, you have non-English error message. For us to be able to help, unfortunately, you have to switch all your locales for Zabbix to some English locale and again, post the error message.

Okey, no problem. I am about to translate the message from spanish to english. Thank you for the feedback

7708:20240722:034051.309 get_perf_counter_value_by_path(): call to PdhOpenQuery() failed: [0x00000102] unable to find message text: [0x0000013D] The system cannot find the text of the message for the message number 0x%1 on the message's file for  %2.

There you have the message translated, thank you. Check it again and let me know if you can find anything else. Referring to your question about the proxy, I can confirm you that it is online and working properly. Is there anything else which you think I need to check? Thanks
